# possible to create latex multicolumns in xtable?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, xtable, r-markdown

I am using xtable with R Markdown and knitr to produce .tex files that I call with \input{}. Works great, but I have not figured out how to create multicolumns like the one shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950703/html-with-multicolumn-table-in-markdown-using-knitr). Does anyone know how to to this?

So far I am using:

```
tbl <- xtable(data, align="l r r r r r")
colnames(tbl) <- c("Variable", 
                  "Mean", "Std Dev", 
                  "Mean", "Std Dev", 
                  "Difference")
caption(tbl) <- c("Table Title")
print(tbl, 
    include.rownames=FALSE,
    caption.placement="top",
    booktabs=TRUE,
    type="latex", 
    file="output.tex")
```

I'd like to have a different grouping header over each "Mean" and "Std Dev" ("Treatment" and "Control").

Alternatively, is there a better method for using R Markdown/knitr to automatically generate tables? I don't want to manually edit the tables because the report needs to generate automatically.

**UPDATE:**
@agstudy: I'm new to latex, but I think this is the output I am looking to produce automatically with xtable (or something like xtable):

```
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
  \toprule
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Treatment} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Control} & \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
  Variable & Mean & Std Dev & Mean & Std Dev & Difference \\ 
  \midrule
  var1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
@Jonathan: it took me a few reads to understand what you were suggesting. I took your recommendation, and it worked.

In the R markdown chunk I now use:

```
tbl <- xtable(data)
print(tbl,
    only.contents=TRUE,
    include.rownames=FALSE,
    type="latex",
    digits(tbl) <- c(0,1,1,1,1,1),
    file="output/tblout.tex")
```

Then in the text, I use:

```
\begin{tabular}{lddddd}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Treatment} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Control} & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    Variable  &  \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean}  &  \multicolumn{1}{r}{Std Dev}  &       \multicolumn{1}{r}{Mean}  &  \multicolumn{1}{r}{Std Dev}  &  \multicolumn{1}{r}{Difference}  \\
\midrule
\input{../output/tblout}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

I'll see if anyone has any other suggestions for a native xtable (or other package) solution. Otherwise, I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: can you please add a sample of the expected latex output?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44324042/r-xtable-with-multicolumns-and-booktabs

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming the form of the table is the same across runs (i.e., only the numbers are changing), my suggestion would be to use the `only.contents` argument to `print.xtable` and code the multi-column headers in by hand. To the best of my knowledge `xtable` is not capable of doing multi-column cells itself.

Answer (score 38):

I think the `add.to.row` option in xtable achieves this perfectly.

Example code here:

```
require(xtable)
age <- sample(c('30-50', '50-70', '70+'), 200, replace=T)
sex <- sample(c('Male', 'Female'), 200, replace=T)
val <- table(age, sex)
val <- rbind(val, formatC(prop.table(val)*100, format='f', digits=1))
val <- structure(val, dim=c(3, 4))
val <- rbind(c('n', '%'), val)
rownames(val) <- c('', sort(unique(age)))
val <- xtable(val)


addtorow <- list()
addtorow$pos <- list(0)
addtorow$command <- paste0(paste0('& \\multicolumn{2}{c}{', sort(unique(sex)), '}', collapse=''), '\\\\')

print(val, add.to.row=addtorow, include.colnames=F)
```

Comment: This worked great for me, I just want to add two hints: 1. the pos variable is a list within a list, not a scalar or a vector (I missed that), and 2. The pos variable can be set to 0 (putting the added line just below the header) or even -1 (putting it above the header, which is where I wanted it)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32490565/3162788) is another example for the use of the `add.to.row` argument along with `\multirow`.

Comment: See the section entitled "Use of add.to.row argument" in the vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf

Answer (score 8):

Consider using the [tables](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf) package.

Comment: As an example, if your data is a data.frame called `dat` that has three columns: `Group`, a factor with levels "Control" and "Treatment"; `var`, a factor with levels "var1", "var2" (etc.); and `value`,  which is numeric, you can do the following: `latex(tabular(var~Heading()*Group*((mean+sd)*Heading()*value), data=dat)` to get the kind of table you want. The examples in `?tables::tabular` help explain the syntax.

Answer (score 5):

This is a child's game with the [`kableExtra` package](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
options(knitr.table.format = "latex")
mx <- matrix(1:6, ncol=3) 
rownames(mx) <- LETTERS[1:NROW(mx)] 
colnames(mx) <- sprintf("Col %s", LETTERS[1:NCOL(mx)])
@

<<results='asis'>>=
kable(mx, booktabs = TRUE, caption = "My table", align = "c") %>% 
  add_header_above(c(" ", "First"=2, "Second"=1)) %>% 
    kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position")
@

<<results='asis'>>=
kable(mx, booktabs = TRUE, caption = "My other table", align = "c") %>% 
  add_header_above(c(" ", "First"=2, "Second"=1)) %>% 
    kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position") %>% 
  group_rows("Nice!", 1, 2)
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually I am doing something like this:

```
tableLines <- print (xtable (mymatrix)) ## no file
multicolumns <- "& \\\\multicolumn{3}{c}{A} & \\\\multicolumn{3}{c}{B} \\\\\\\\"
tableLines <- sub ("\\\\toprule\\n", paste0 ("\\\\toprule\n", multicolumns, "\n"), tableLines) ## booktabs = TRUE
tableLines <- sub ("\\\\hline\\n",   paste0 ("\\\\hline\n",   multicolumns, "\n"), tableLines) ## booktabs = FALSE
writeLines (tableLines, con = "myfile")
```

Pay attention to the many `\\\\` needed. Backslashes are lost in the `sub` and `paste` commands.

Comment: Note that R 4.0's raw character constants can help cut down on the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late to the game here is my answer, which is similar to ashkan, but more general and allows for different parameters.

First of all, why a new answer? Well, I needed an output without a table-environment (I want to write my captions etc inside my tex-document not inside my r-code) which `kableExtra` does not seem to provide (correct me if I am wrong).
But I also wanted flexibility with the inputs (i.e., with and without line, different spans etc).

The result is a function `construct_header()` that constructs the header for us.

First a short example:

```
library(xtable)
set.seed(123)
df <- matrix(round(rnorm(16), 2), ncol = 4) 
df <- cbind(paste("Var", 1:4), df)
colnames(df) <- c("Var", rep(c("X", "Y"), 2))
df
#      Var     X       Y       X       Y      
# [1,] "Var 1" "-0.56" "0.13"  "-0.69" "0.4"  
# [2,] "Var 2" "-0.23" "1.72"  "-0.45" "0.11" 
# [3,] "Var 3" "1.56"  "0.46"  "1.22"  "-0.56"
# [4,] "Var 4" "0.07"  "-1.27" "0.36"  "1.79" 

a_header <- construct_header(
  # the data.frame or matrix that should be plotted  
  df,
  # the labels of the groups that we want to insert
  grp_names = c("", "Group A", "Group B"), 
  # the number of columns each group spans
  span = c(1, 2, 2), 
  # the alignment of each group, can be a single character (lcr) or a vector
  align = "c"
)

print(xtable(df), add.to.row = a_header, include.rownames = F, hline.after = F)
# % latex table generated in R 3.4.2 by xtable 1.8-2 package
# % Fri Oct 27 16:39:44 2017
# \begin{table}[ht]
# \centering
# \begin{tabular}{lllll}
#   \hline
#   \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Group A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Group B} \\  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
#   Var & X & Y & X & Y \\ 
#   \hline
#   Var 1 & -0.56 & 0.13 & -0.69 & 0.4 \\ 
#   Var 2 & -0.23 & 1.72 & -0.45 & 0.11 \\ 
#   Var 3 & 1.56 & 0.46 & 1.22 & -0.56 \\ 
#   Var 4 & 0.07 & -1.27 & 0.36 & 1.79 \\ 
#   \hline
# \end{tabular}
# \end{table}
```

Note that we have to specify `hline.after = FALSE` (important for me, but omitted here is the possibility to specify `floating = FALSE`).

Which results in this table (note that this approach needs the `booktabs` package to be loaded in LaTeX):

[image: table]

You can specify to omit the lines `construct_header(..., draw_line = FALSE)`, align the groups, and have them span in different ways, i.e.,

```
ugly_header <- construct_header(df, c("One", "Two", "Three"), c(2, 1, 2), c("l", "c", "r"))
print(xtable(df), add.to.row = ugly_header, include.rownames = F, hline.after = F)
```

which results in this:
[image]

The code for the function is this:

```
#' Constructs a header i.e., groups for an xtable
#'
#' @param df a data.frame or matrix
#' @param grp_names the names of the groups
#' @param span where the groups span
#' @param align the alignment of the groups, defaults to center
#' @param draw_line if the group-names should be underlined
#'
#' @return a list that can be given to the \code{add.to.row} argument of the of \code{print.xtable}
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' library(xtable)
#' mx <- matrix(rnorm(16), ncol = 4) 
#' mx <- cbind(paste("Var", 1:4), mx)
#' colnames(mx) <- c("Var", rep(c("X", "Y"), 2))
#' 
#' addtorow <- construct_header(mx, c("", "Group A", "Group B"), span = c(1, 2, 2), "c")
#' print(xtable(mx), add.to.row = addtorow, include.rownames = F, hline.after = F)
construct_header <- function(df, grp_names, span, align = "c", draw_line = T) {
  if (length(align) == 1) align <- rep(align, length(grp_names))
  if (!all.equal(length(grp_names), length(span), length(align)))
    stop("grp_names and span have to have the same length!")

  if (ncol(df) < sum(span)) stop("Span has to be less or equal to the number of columns of df") 

  header <- mapply(function(s, a, grp) sprintf("\\multicolumn{%i}{%s}{%s}", s, a, grp),
                   span, align, grp_names)
  header <- paste(header, collapse = " & ")
  header <- paste0(header, " \\\\")

  if (draw_line) {
    # where do we span the lines:
    min_vals <- c(1, 1 + cumsum(span)[1:(length(span) - 1)])
    max_vals <- cumsum(span)
    line <- ifelse(grp_names == "", "", 
                   sprintf("\\cmidrule(lr){%i-%i}", min_vals, max_vals))
    line <- paste(line[line != ""], collapse = " ")

    header <- paste0(header, "  ", line, "\n  ")
  }

  addtorow <- list(pos = list(-1, -1, nrow(df)),
                   command = c("\\hline\n  ", header, "\\hline\n  "))
  return(addtorow)
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, but I think that for '\cmidrule', we need to add use the \usepackage{booktabs}, isn't it?

Comment: That is correct, thanks for pointing it out. I added the information in the answer.