# knitr/rmarkdown/Latex: How to custom justify xtable columns using dcolumn, while suppressing other dcolumn formatting

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I have a table of values where each cell has a number, a space, and then another number in parentheses. I'm using `xtable` to render this table in the document. I'd like the numbers to be justified on the left parenthesis (or on the space). I've used the `latex` `dcolumn` package to create a command to justify on the left parenthesis. However, that changes other aspects of how the table is formatted and I'd like to prevent that from happening.

I know just enough `latex` to be dangerous and am not sure of the next step. Below is a reproducible example showing what the table looks like now and explaining how I'd actually like it to look. I'd like to figure out how to get the formatting I want programmatically, within the `rmarkdown` document, so that I don't have to hack the latex afterward. Also, I'm not wedded to this particular method of justifying the table values, so please feel free to suggest another approach if I'm on the wrong track.

Since this question focuses on using latex in the context of `r`, `knitr` and `rmarkdown`, I thought it would be better to ask it here, but please let me know if I should move it to the `Tex` Stack Exchange site instead.

#### `header.tex` file containing the `dcolumn` command:

```
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{Q}{D{(}{(}{-1}}
```

#### `rmarkdown` document:

````
---
title: "Test"
date: "July 19, 2016"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
fontsize: 11pt
geometry: margin=1in
graphics: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.align="center")
```

```{r}
library(xtable)

# Data frame to create table
tab1 = structure(list(Term = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Fall 2007", 
"Spring 2008", "Fall 2008", "Spring 2009", "Fall 2009", "Spring 2010", 
"Fall 2010", "Spring 2011", "Fall 2011", "Spring 2012", "Fall 2012", 
"Spring 2013", "Fall 2013", "Spring 2014", "Fall 2014", "Spring 2015", 
"Fall 2015", "Spring 2016", "Fall 2016"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), `BIO 10` = c("89 (2)", "96 (2)", "77 (1)", "103 (3)", 
"81 (1)"), `BIO 20` = c("194 (5)", "175 (3)", "176 (8)", "168 (3)", 
"170 (4)"), `BIO 30` = c("153 (2)", "154 (14)", "188 (7)", "192 (9)", 
"183 (8)"), `BIO 40` = c("284 (23)", "296 (5)", "267 (17)", "296 (16)", 
"279 (7)"), `BIO 50` = c("88 (1)", "107 (5)", "98 (1)", "109 (7)", 
"93 (5)")), .Names = c("Term", "BIO 10", "BIO 20", "BIO 30", 
"BIO 40", "BIO 50"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

```{r results="asis"}
print.xtable(
  xtable(tab1, 
         label="tab:tab1",
         caption = "Default Table"), 
  size="small",
  include.rownames=FALSE, comment=FALSE, caption.placement="top"
)
```

```{r results="asis"}
print.xtable(
  xtable(tab1, 
         label="tab:tab2",
         caption = "Columns aligned at left parenthesis",
         align=c("llQQQQQ")), 
  size="small",
  include.rownames=FALSE, comment=FALSE, caption.placement="top"
)
```
````

Below is the output of the `rmarkdown` document. Table 1 is the default table created by `xtable`. Table 2 uses the `dcolumn` command in the `my_header.tex` file. In Table 2, the left-hand number in each cell is right-aligned, which is what I want. However, `docolumn` has changed the formatting in other ways that I don't want:

1. Column headers should look like the column headers in Table 1, meaning there should be no italics and there should be a space between BIO and the following number.
2. Column widths should be more like the widths in Table 1.
3. In the data columns, there should be a space between the first number and the number in parentheses. For example, 
   "89(2)" should be "89 (2)".
4. If possible, it would be even better to have both numbers separately right-aligned. This means that there could be either one or two spaces between the numbers, depending on whether the number in parentheses has, respectively two digits or one digit.

[image]

Comment: @user20650, just curious why you deleted your answer. It seems to work and it even justifies *both* sets of numbers separately.

Comment: Hi eipi10; I deleted it as Martin had rolled back his answer to his original (at that point), and I didnt think ny answer was sufficiently different to keep it (and I knew you would still be able to see it). ps: taken from another iteration of Martin's answer, you can get nicer spacing using `c("l","l", rep(c("r@{\\hskip 0in \\;}", "r"),5)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated my answer in that sense, that you dont need `dcolumn` anymore. It is a bit of a mix between using R's regex functionalities and adding primitive LaTeX commands such as`{\hskip 0.5em}`. The thing is, that you can add these primitives in (as far as I know) any LaTeX environment in order to format your paragraphs and such.

So using `apply` we *reformat* the **content** of the table cells depending on whether the number in parenthesis has 1 or 2 digits and then add a proper horizontal spacing.

By using `sanitize.text.function = identity` inside of `print.xtable` we make sure that these LaTeX commands do not get deleted when the `data.frame` is processed by `xtable`.

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.align="center")
```

```{r}
library(xtable)
namesVec <- c("Term", "BIO 10", "BIO 20", "BIO 30", 
"BIO 40", "BIO 50")
# Data frame to create table
tab1 = structure(list(Term = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Fall 2007", 
"Spring 2008", "Fall 2008", "Spring 2009", "Fall 2009", "Spring 2010", 
"Fall 2010", "Spring 2011", "Fall 2011", "Spring 2012", "Fall 2012", 
"Spring 2013", "Fall 2013", "Spring 2014", "Fall 2014", "Spring 2015", 
"Fall 2015", "Spring 2016", "Fall 2016"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), `BIO 10` = c("89 (2)", "96 (2)", "77 (1)", "103 (3)", 
"81 (1)"), `BIO 20` = c("194 (5)", "175 (3)", "176 (8)", "168 (3)", 
"170 (4)"), `BIO 30` = c("153 (2)", "154 (14)", "188 (7)", "192 (9)", 
"183 (8)"), `BIO 40` = c("284 (23)", "296 (5)", "267 (17)", "296 (16)", 
"279 (7)"), `BIO 50` = c("88 (1)", "107 (5)", "98 (1)", "109 (7)", 
"93 (5)")), .Names = paste("\\textnormal{", namesVec, "}"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

tab1 <-apply(tab1, 2, function(x) { 
  tmp <- nchar(gsub(".*\\( ?([0-9]+).*","\\1", x))
  skip <-ifelse(tmp == 1, "{\\\\hskip 1em}(", "{\\\\hskip 0.5em}(")
  ifelse(tmp == 1, gsub(x, pattern = " \\(", replacement = paste("{\\\\hskip 1em}(")),
                   gsub(x, pattern = " \\(", replacement = paste("{\\\\hskip 0.5em}(")))
})
```


```{r results="asis"}
print.xtable(
  xtable(tab1, 
         label="tab:tab2",
         caption = "Columns aligned at left parenthesis",
         align=c("llrrrrr")), 
  size="small",
  include.rownames=FALSE, comment=FALSE, caption.placement="top"
, sanitize.text.function = identity)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks Martin. I see what you've done, but can you explain (to a Latex-challenged person like me) why it works?

Comment: Sure, will do tomorrow. I'm out with my gf right now ;)

Comment: So your gf takes precedence over an SO question? Maybe you need to reexamine your priorities :).

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar approach to Martin;s now edited away answer. Its probably easier (at least for a non-latex speaker like me) to align the numbers, and numbers in parenthesis separately, so split these into separate columns. You can then use `\multicolumn` to group the columns, and define the headers (see [possible to create latex multicolumns in xtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984470/possible-to-create-latex-multicolumns-in-xtable))

````
```{r results="asis", echo=FALSE}    

tab1 = structure(list(Term = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Fall 2007", 
"Spring 2008", "Fall 2008", "Spring 2009", "Fall 2009", "Spring 2010", 
"Fall 2010", "Spring 2011", "Fall 2011", "Spring 2012", "Fall 2012", 
"Spring 2013", "Fall 2013", "Spring 2014", "Fall 2014", "Spring 2015", 
"Fall 2015", "Spring 2016", "Fall 2016"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), `BIO 10` = c("89 (2)", "96 (2)", "77 (1)", "103 (3)", 
"81 (1)"), `BIO 20` = c("194 (5)", "175 (3)", "176 (8)", "168 (3)", 
"170 (4)"), `BIO 30` = c("153 (2)", "154 (14)", "188 (7)", "192 (9)", 
"183 (8)"), `BIO 40` = c("284 (23)", "296 (5)", "267 (17)", "296 (16)", 
"279 (7)"), `BIO 50` = c("88 (1)", "107 (5)", "98 (1)", "109 (7)", 
"93 (5)")), .Names = c("Term", "BIO 10", "BIO 20", "BIO 30", 
"BIO 40", "BIO 50"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

tab2 <- cbind(tab1[1], do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(tab1[-1], function(x) 
  do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(x), " ")))))

addtorow <- list(list(0), paste(names(tab1)[1], paste0('& \\multicolumn{2}{l}{', names(tab1)[-1], '}', collapse=''), '\\\\'))

library(xtable)

print.xtable(
  xtable(tab2,
         align=c("l","l", rep(c("r@{\\hskip 0in}", "r"),5))),
  include.rownames=FALSE, ,
  add.to.row=addtorow, include.colnames=FALSE)

```
````

[image]