# How to format a complex table for rmarkdown PDF output

Tags: r, formatting, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I have a table that I'd like to output in PDF format from an `rmarkdown` document. However, with my limited Latex skills, I can't figure out how to get spanning columns, cell borders, and font faces the way I want them using `xtable` with various `Latex` additions.

I was able to get pretty much what I wanted using the `FlexTable` function from the `ReporteRs` package, but it looks like `FlexTable` can only be used with `rmarkdown` to produce html output, but not PDF output.

So, I'm looking for help with formatting my table using `xtable`, or any other R package or (possibly custom) R function that can be used for programmatically creating reasonably complex tables for PDF output. Also, if there's some way to coax `FlexTable` to work with PDF output, that would be great too.

Below I create a table using `FlexTable` so you can see what I'm aiming for. Following that, I provide a sample `rmarkdown` document showing where I've gotten so far in my (somewhat lame) efforts to create a similar table using `xtable`.

### `ReporteRs::FlexTable` version

First, let's create the data that will go into the table:

```
library(ReporteRs)

x = structure(c(34L, 6L, 9L, 35L), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    Actual = c("Fail", "Pass"), Predicted = c("Fail", "Pass")), .Names = c("Actual", 
"Predicted")), class = "table")

x=cbind(x, prop.table(x), prop.table(x, 1), prop.table(x,2))
x[, -c(1,2)] = sapply(x[,-c(1,2)], function(i) paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", i*100),"%"))
x = cbind(Actual=rownames(x), x)
```

Now for the FlexTable creation and formatting:

```
# Set up general table properties and formatting
cell_p = cellProperties(padding.right=3, padding.left=3)
par_p = parProperties(text.align="right")

# Create table
ft = FlexTable(x, header.columns=FALSE, body.cell.props=cell_p, body.par.props=par_p)

# Add three header rows
ft = addHeaderRow(ft, text.properties=textBold(), c("","Predicted"),
                  colspan=c(1,8), par.properties=parCenter())

ft = addHeaderRow(ft, text.properties=textBold(), 
                  value=c("", "Count", "Overall\nPercent", "Row\nPercent", "Column\nPercent"),
                  colspan=c(1,rep(2,4)), par.properties=parCenter())

ft = addHeaderRow(ft, text.properties=textItalic(), par.properties=parCenter(),
                  value=colnames(x))

# Format specific cells
ft[1:2, 1, to="header", side="left"] = borderProperties(color="white")
ft[1:2, 1, to="header", side="top"] = borderProperties(color="white")

ft[3, 1, to="header"] = textProperties(font.style="normal", font.weight="bold")
ft[ , 1] = textProperties(font.style="italic")

ft[ , 2:3] = cellProperties(padding.right=7, padding.left=7)
ft[ , 1] = cellProperties(padding.right=10, padding.left=10)

# Display ft
ft
```

And here's what the final table looks like (this is a PNG screenshot of the table displayed in a browser window):

[image]

Now for my attempt at doing the same thing with `xtable`.

### `xtable` version

Here's the `rmarkdown` document and the `header.tex` file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "eipi10"
date: "11/19/2016"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex 
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message=FALSE)
```

```{r}
# Fake confusion matrix to work with
x = structure(c(34L, 6L, 9L, 35L), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    Actual = c("Fail", "Pass"), Predicted = c("Fail", "Pass")), .Names = c("Actual", 
"Predicted")), class = "table")

x=cbind(x, prop.table(x), prop.table(x, 1), prop.table(x,2))
x[, -c(1,2)] = sapply(x[,-c(1,2)], function(i) paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", i*100),"%"))
x = cbind(Actual=rownames(x), x)
```  

```{r use_xtable, results="asis"}
# Output the confusion matrix created above as a latex table
library(xtable)
options(xtable.comment=FALSE)

# This is a modified version of a function created in the following SO answer:
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/38978541/496488
make_addtorow <- function(row.name, terms, colSpan, width) {
  # Custom row function
  paste0(row.name, 
  paste0('& \\multicolumn{', colSpan, '}{C{', width, 'cm}}{', 
         terms, 
         '}', 
        collapse=''), 
  '\\\\')
}

addtorow <- list()
addtorow$pos <- list(-1,-1,-1,-1) 
addtorow$command <- c(
  "\\hline",
  make_addtorow("", c("Predicted"), 8, 12),
  "\\hline",
  make_addtorow("", c("Count", "Percent", "Row Percent", "Column Percent"), 2, 3)
  )

xtbl = xtable(x, caption="Created with xtable")

align(xtbl) <- c("|L{0cm}|", "L{1.2cm}|", rep("R{1cm}|",8))

print(xtbl, 
      include.rownames=FALSE, 
      tabular.environment="tabularx", 
      width="0.92\\textwidth",
      add.to.row = addtorow)
```
````

File `header.tex` that is used for knitting the rmarkdown document above:

```
% xtable manual: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}  
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\
\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\
\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\
\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\tabularxbackslash}p{#1}}

% Caption on top
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14862/4762
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}
```

And here's what the table looks like in the PDF output:

[image]

Comment: If you are looking for a pure TeX solution: there always is [tex.se] to ask on.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this programmatically from within the rmarkdown document without having to hard-code the formatting, so that it's reproducible and flexible. My assumption is that I need to write R code that outputs the appropriate Latex markup, but that's not essential. For example, if there were a way to pipe the `FlexTable` object (`ft` in my code example) to some function that converted it to something that can be output as a correctly formatted table when I knit to PDF, that's fine too.

Comment: There might be a way to do this with the [`tables` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf), which has lots of multicolumn and formatting options and a `latex` print function. I haven't quite figured out how it works, yet, though.

Comment: Thanks @alistaire. I've looked at the `tables` package before (inlcuding trying to create the table in my example), and I agree that it looks like it ought to be able to create the kind of table I'm looking for. However, I find the package very confusing and wasn't able to get very far. If you can figure out how it works, I'd love to see an example.

Comment: @user20650, I'm curious why you deleted your answer. I thought it was good.

Comment: @eipi; I wasn't happy with it, and after several approaches to improve the formatting (bold which is straightforward / italic less so as it messed up the spacing)  I gave up!.

Comment: @user20650, well I thought it was a good effort and I hope you'll consider undeleting it. That will also create the opportunity for others to suggest improvements.

Comment: @eipi10 ; okay fair point. undeleted and added a couple of other iterations i tried in case someone can further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very simple to do using the `add_header_above` command from the KableExtra-package. You can add as many column groupings as you want. Here is what I would do:

```
d <- mtcars[1:5,1:5]
kable(d,longtable = T, booktabs = T) %>%
   add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2" = 3)) %>%
   add_header_above(c("","Groups" = 5))
```

[image]

Comment: I've been using `kableExtra` for a while. It vastly reduced the pain of generating complex table layouts compared with previous options.

Answer (score 10):

Quoting [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699550/how-to-format-a-complex-table-for-rmarkdown-pdf-output#comment68641466_40699550):

> I'm looking for a way to do this programmatically from within the rmarkdown document without having to hard-code the formatting, so that it's reproducible and flexible.

The following solution uses a hard-coded "template", but the template can be filled with any data (provided it has the same 2x8 structure).

The generated table looks like this:

[image: Output]

Full code below.

---

Basically, the final table consists of 9 columns, so the basic LaTeX structure is

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
% rest of table
\end{tabular}
```

However, it is convenient to fix the width of the cells. This is possible with the custom column type `C` (taken from [here on TEX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/37118)), which allows for centered content with fixed width. This, together with the [more compact syntax for repeating column types](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233603/37118) gives:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c *{8}{|C{1cm}}|}
% rest of table
\end{tabular}
```

(First column centered with flexible width, then 8 centered columns, each 1cm wide).

The cells spanning multiple columns are possible using `\multicolumn`. These cells should also have a fixed width in order to have the cell captions break into two lines. Note that it is a fallacy to assume that the cells spanning two 1cm-columns should have a width of 2cm because the two spanned cells have additional padding between them. Some measurement revealed that about 2.436cm delivers good results.

Remark on the first column: Although `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` looks useless at first sight, it is useful for changing the column type (including left/right) borders for a single cell. I used it to drop the leftmost vertical line in the first two rows.

`\cline{x-y}` provides horizontal lines that span only the columns `x`to `y`.

Taking these pieces together gives:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c *{8}{|C{1cm}}|} \cline{2-9}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Predicted}} \\ \cline{2-9}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Count}} & \multicolumn{2}{C{2.436cm}|}{\textbf{Overall Percent}} & \multicolumn{2}{C{2.436cm}|}{\textbf{Row \newline Percent}} & \multicolumn{2}{C{2.436cm}|}{\textbf{Column Percent}} \\ \hline
% rest of table
\end{tabular}
```

Regarding the data, I dropped the last line of the code that generated to sample data to get:

```
> x <- structure(c(34L, 6L, 9L, 35L), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(Actual = c("Fail", "Pass"), Predicted = c("Fail", "Pass")), .Names = c("Actual", "Predicted")), class = "table")
> x <- cbind(x, prop.table(x), prop.table(x, 1), prop.table(x,2))
> x[, -c(1,2)] <- sapply(x[,-c(1,2)], function(i) paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", i*100),"%"))
> x
     Fail Pass Fail    Pass    Fail    Pass    Fail    Pass   
Fail "34" "9"  "40.5%" "10.7%" "79.1%" "20.9%" "85.0%" "20.5%"
Pass "6"  "35" "7.1%"  "41.7%" "14.6%" "85.4%" "15.0%" "79.5%"
```

To set the column and row names in italics, apply

```
colnames(x) <- sprintf("\\emph{%s}", colnames(x)) # highlight colnames
rownames(x) <- sprintf("\\emph{%s}", rownames(x)) # highlight rownames
```

Then, the following `xtable` code can be used:

```
print(xtable(x),
      only.contents = TRUE, 
      comment = FALSE,
      sanitize.colnames.function = identity, 
      sanitize.rownames.function = identity, 
      hline.after = 0:2)
```

The argument `only.contents` suppresses the enclosing `tabular` environment. Assigning the identity function to `sanitize.colnames.function` and `sanitize.rownames.function` means "don't sanitize". We need this because column and row names contain special LaTeX characters that should not be escaped (`\emph`).

The output should replace the `%rest of table` placeholder from above.

---

Conceptually, the code uses `xtable` to generate only the table body but not the header because it is much easier to write the header manually.

Although the whole table header is "hard-coded", the data can be changed as required.

Don't forget to escape all `\` with a second `\`! Also, the following must be added to the header (`header.tex`):

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/37118
```

---

I wrapped all the elements outlined above in a function `PrintConfusionMatrix` that can be reused with any 2x8 data frame providing the data and column / row names.

---

## Full code:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: yes
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
---


```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(xtable)

# Sample data from question
x <- structure(c(34L, 6L, 9L, 35L), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(Actual = c("Fail", "Pass"), Predicted = c("Fail", "Pass")), .Names = c("Actual", "Predicted")), class = "table")
x <- cbind(x, prop.table(x), prop.table(x, 1), prop.table(x,2))
x[, -c(1,2)] <- sapply(x[,-c(1,2)], function(i) paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", i*100),"%"))
#x <- cbind(Actual=rownames(x), x) # dropped; better not to add row names to data

PrintConfusionMatrix <- function(data, ...) {

  stopifnot(all(dim(x) == c(2, 8)))

  colnames(x) <- sprintf("\\emph{%s}", colnames(x)) # highlight colnames
  rownames(x) <- sprintf("\\emph{%s}", rownames(x)) # highlight rownames

  cat('\\begin{tabular}{|c *{8}{|C{1cm}}|} \\cline{2-9}
    \\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\multicolumn{8}{c|}{\\textbf{Predicted}} \\\\ \\cline{2-9}
    \\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\\textbf{Count}} & \\multicolumn{2}{C{2.436cm}|}{\\textbf{Overall Percent}} & \\multicolumn{2}{C{2.436cm}|}{\\textbf{Row \\newline Percent}} & \\multicolumn{2}{C{2.436cm}|}{\\textbf{Column Percent}} \\\\ \\hline
    \\textbf{Actual} ')

  print(xtable(x),
        only.contents = TRUE, 
        comment = FALSE,
        sanitize.colnames.function = identity, 
        sanitize.rownames.function = identity, 
        hline.after = 0:2,
        ...)
  cat("\\end{tabular}")
}
```

```{r, results='asis'}
PrintConfusionMatrix(x)
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would it be possible to center `Count`, `Overall Percent`, etc. over the columns they span and also have the separator lines extend up between them?

Comment: @eipi10 Sure … extending the vertical lines is simple: Just add `|` to the column specifications in `\multicolumn`. Proper centering is more difficult (didn't notice that my first try was not centered), but I found a solution – see edit (soon).