# How to get xtable to not ignore whitspace or to align decimal points respectively?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, xtable

I'm about to write a function that yields both a screen output and a LaTeX/PDF-output of lists of regression tables and have problems with the decimal point alignment of the latter.

From this toy table `regmat`,

```
                1                 2                 3                 4                
(Intercept)     "      33.99 ***" "    3370.83 ***" "      39.42 ***" "      46.80 ***"
                "      (1.89)   " "    (260.49)   " "      (2.64)   " "      (6.37)   "
cyl             "       ---     " "       ---     " "      -1.51 ** " "       ---     "
                "       ---     " "       ---     " "      (0.42)   " "       ---     "
factor(am)1     "       ---     " "     180.92    " "       0.18    " "       0.19    "
                "       ---     " "    (139.63)   " "      (1.30)   " "      (1.49)   "
factor(cyl)6    "      -4.26 ** " "    -303.13 *  " "       ---     " "      -1.28    "
                "      (1.39)   " "    (140.73)   " "       ---     " "      (1.53)   "
factor(cyl)8    "      -6.07 ***" "    -216.37    " "       ---     " "      -1.39    "
                "      (1.65)   " "    (228.43)   " "       ---     " "      (2.16)   "
hp              "       ---     " "      -3.21 *  " "       ---     " "      -0.10 ** "
                "       ---     " "      (1.37)   " "       ---     " "      (0.03)   "
wt              "      -3.21 ***" "    -249.68 ** " "      -3.13 ** " "      -7.12 ** "
                "      (0.75)   " "     (88.56)   " "      (0.91)   " "      (2.24)   "
wt:hp           "       ---     " "       ---     " "       ---     " "       0.02 *  "
                "       ---     " "       ---     " "       ---     " "      (0.01)   "
Deviance        "    1126.05    " "11260471.88    " "    1126.05    " "    1126.05    "
Df              "      31       " "      31       " "      31       " "      31       "
Log-Likelihood  "     -73.31    " "    -217.60    " "     -73.99    " "     -67.34    "
AIC             "     156.62    " "     449.20    " "     157.99    " "     150.69    "
BIC             "     163.95    " "     459.46    " "     165.32    " "     162.41    "
Resid. deviance "     183.06    " " 1510255.92    " "     191.05    " "     126.07    "
Resid. Df       "      28       " "      26       " "      28       " "      25       "
Num. obs.       "      32       " "      32       " "      32       " "      32       "
```

I get a nice **screen output** with `as.data.frame(regmat)`;

```
> as.data.frame(regmat)
                              1               2               3               4
(Intercept)           33.99 ***     3370.83 ***       39.42 ***       46.80 ***
                      (1.89)        (260.49)          (2.64)          (6.37)   
cyl                    ---             ---            -1.51 **         ---     
                       ---             ---            (0.42)           ---     
factor(am)1            ---           180.92            0.18            0.19    
                       ---          (139.63)          (1.30)          (1.49)   
factor(cyl)6          -4.26 **      -303.13 *          ---            -1.28    
                      (1.39)        (140.73)           ---            (1.53)   
factor(cyl)8          -6.07 ***     -216.37            ---            -1.39    
                      (1.65)        (228.43)           ---            (2.16)   
hp                     ---            -3.21 *          ---            -0.10 ** 
                       ---            (1.37)           ---            (0.03)   
wt                    -3.21 ***     -249.68 **        -3.13 **        -7.12 ** 
                      (0.75)         (88.56)          (0.91)          (2.24)   
wt:hp                  ---             ---             ---             0.02 *  
                       ---             ---             ---            (0.01)   
Deviance            1126.05     11260471.88         1126.05         1126.05    
Df                    31              31              31              31       
Log-Likelihood       -73.31         -217.60          -73.99          -67.34    
AIC                  156.62          449.20          157.99          150.69    
BIC                  163.95          459.46          165.32          162.41    
Resid. deviance      183.06      1510255.92          191.05          126.07    
Resid. Df             28              26              28              25       
Num. obs.             32              32              32              32
```

the decimal points are all aligned, even in lines with parentheses, and the integers in the lower GOF section end before the points.

Now I **want a similar LaTeX/PDF output** with `xtable` using `rmarkdown` and this code,

```
library(xtable)
xtbl <- xtable(regmat, comment=FALSE)
align(xtbl) <- c("L{2.4cm}", rep(c("L{2cm}@{\\hskip 0.1cm}"), 4))
print(xtbl,
      tabular.environment="tabularx",
      width=".5\\textwidth",
      hline.after=c(-1, 0, 16, nrow(regmat)),
      comment=FALSE)
```

where the YAML looks like this

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: "X:/<myDir>/header.tex"
classoption: 
- a4paper
- landscape
geometry: margin=2cm
header-includes: 
- \pagenumbering{gobble}
- \usepackage{dcolumn}
---
```

and `header.tex` -- as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38978541/6574038) -- looks like so,

```
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\
\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\
\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\
\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\tabularxbackslash}p{#1}}
```

obtaining this **failed LaTeX/PDF-table result**:

[image]

Looks not bad, but as one can see the left-alignment starts at the first non-space character and all the white spaces seem to be ignored.

In `rep(c("L{2cm}@{\\hskip 0.1cm}")` I tried all of `L`, `C`, `R`, and `P` of the `header.tex`, but none of them aligns the values at the decimal point, i.e. doesn't seem to use the package `\usepackage{dcolumn}` which is written to align decimal points.

I don't care about `dcolumn`, though, I just find it weird that my white spaces are ignored.

**How can I get the same alignment in my LaTeX-PDF-table as in the screen output shown above, either with `dcolumn` or by not ignoring the white spaces?**

#### Data

```
regmat <- structure(c("      33.99 ***", "      (1.89)   ", "       ---     ", 
"       ---     ", "       ---     ", "       ---     ", "      -4.26 ** ", 
"      (1.39)   ", "      -6.07 ***", "      (1.65)   ", "       ---     ", 
"       ---     ", "      -3.21 ***", "      (0.75)   ", "       ---     ", 
"       ---     ", "    1126.05    ", "      31       ", "     -73.31    ", 
"     156.62    ", "     163.95    ", "     183.06    ", "      28       ", 
"      32       ", "    3370.83 ***", "    (260.49)   ", "       ---     ", 
"       ---     ", "     180.92    ", "    (139.63)   ", "    -303.13 *  ", 
"    (140.73)   ", "    -216.37    ", "    (228.43)   ", "      -3.21 *  ", 
"      (1.37)   ", "    -249.68 ** ", "     (88.56)   ", "       ---     ", 
"       ---     ", "11260471.88    ", "      31       ", "    -217.60    ", 
"     449.20    ", "     459.46    ", " 1510255.92    ", "      26       ", 
"      32       ", "      39.42 ***", "      (2.64)   ", "      -1.51 ** ", 
"      (0.42)   ", "       0.18    ", "      (1.30)   ", "       ---     ", 
"       ---     ", "       ---     ", "       ---     ", "       ---     ", 
"       ---     ", "      -3.13 ** ", "      (0.91)   ", "       ---     ", 
"       ---     ", "    1126.05    ", "      31       ", "     -73.99    ", 
"     157.99    ", "     165.32    ", "     191.05    ", "      28       ", 
"      32       ", "      46.80 ***", "      (6.37)   ", "       ---     ", 
"       ---     ", "       0.19    ", "      (1.49)   ", "      -1.28    ", 
"      (1.53)   ", "      -1.39    ", "      (2.16)   ", "      -0.10 ** ", 
"      (0.03)   ", "      -7.12 ** ", "      (2.24)   ", "       0.02 *  ", 
"      (0.01)   ", "    1126.05    ", "      31       ", "     -67.34    ", 
"     150.69    ", "     162.41    ", "     126.07    ", "      25       ", 
"      32       "), .Dim = c(24L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("(Intercept)", 
" ", "cyl", "   ", "factor(am)1", "     ", "factor(cyl)6", "       ", 
"factor(cyl)8", "         ", "hp", "           ", "wt", "             ", 
"wt:hp", "               ", "Deviance", "Df", "Log-Likelihood", 
"AIC", "BIC", "Resid. deviance", "Resid. Df", "Num. obs."), c("1", 
"2", "3", "4")))
```

Comment: I haven't used `xtable` in a while, but the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964540/how-to-decimal-align-regression-coefficients-in-latex-table-output-in-rmarkdown) that I asked a while back might be helpful.

Comment: @eipi10 Actually, I referred to this question in my question. It's a different attempt and when you look closer the GOFs aren't actually aligned.

Comment: Ah, I missed that! There are a number of more recent packages that try to make table creation easier with R. I haven't used [`huxtable`](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/huxreg.html), but [it seems](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/reference/align.html) to have the means to align on a decimal point.

Comment: @eipi10 I've tried `library(huxtable); set_align(huxtable(regmat), value=".")` but that doesn't seem to work (perhaps due to the `" --- "` cells).

Comment: @jay.sf your problem is that your table has lots of spaces in already. huxtable attempts to respect these when it does the alignment. If you do `regmat2 <- trimws(regmat); regmat2 <- as_huxtable(regmat2); align(regmat2) <- ".";` you will get a nicer result - still not perfect, as there is no easy way to align on decimal points in either HTML or TeX. One workaround is to set the font to `"cmtt"` or another fixed width font.