# Two way frequency table in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, contingency

In what way can I construct a two-way frequency table in Rmarkdown?
Something like:

[image: this]

I tried to use both the kable function from the knitr package and the datable function from the DT package, but none gave me the desired result.

Update:
Reproducible code with example.

```
a <- sample(x = c(1,2,3), size = 1000, replace = T)
b <- sample(x = c('a', 'b', 'c'), size = 1000, replace = T)

df <- data.frame(vertical_title = a, horitzontal_title = b)

table(df)

              horitzontal_title
vertical_title   a   b   c
             1 118  98 106
             2 106  95 121
             3 128 114 114
```

I want 'vertical_title' and 'horizontal_title' to be visible for my table in Rmarkdown.

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer like this. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips on how to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Good point Florian, I was a bit in a hurry. I added a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the table as follows:

````
---
title: Example 1
output: pdf_document
---

### This is a test

```{r,results='asis',echo=FALSE}

library(xtable)
a <- sample(x = c(1,2,3), size = 1000, replace = T)
b <- sample(x = c('a', 'b', 'c'), size = 1000, replace = T)

df <- data.frame(vertical_title = a, horitzontal_title = b)
df <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(df)) 


print(xtable(df,
            align = "|l|rrr|",
            caption = "Test"),
      caption.placement = 'top',
      comment = F,
      scalebox=1,
      include.rownames = T,
      hline.after = c(-1,0,nrow(df)),
      vline.after = c(1),
      format.args=list(big.mark = ",", decimal.mark = "."))


```
````

See here for a way to add multicolumn and multirows for your titles:

[R package xtable, how to create a latextable with multiple rows and columns from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036754/r-package-xtable-how-to-create-a-latextable-with-multiple-rows-and-columns-from)

Hope this helps!