# using Hmisc function latex in knitr evironment

Tags: r, latex, knitr, multiple-columns, hmisc

I am using knitr to produce pdf reports. One thing I am trying to do is to add multicloumns to a table. I am referting to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950703/html-with-multicolumn-table-in-markdown-using-knitr). The question is how can I put the code showed in the post in my Rnw file. This is what I've tried in my Rnw file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}


<<echo=FALSE, results = "asis">>=
mx <- matrix(1:6, ncol=3) 
rownames(mx) <- LETTERS[1:NROW(mx)] 
colnames(mx) <- sprintf("Col %s", LETTERS[1:NCOL(mx)])
latex(mx, n.rgroup=c(2), rgroup=c("Nice!"),
      n.cgroup=c(2,1), cgroup=c("First", "Second"),
      file="", 
      ctable=TRUE)
@

\end{document}
```

and I use knit('test.Rnw') to convert it to tex file. And this is how the tex file looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}\usepackage[]{graphicx}\usepackage[]{color}
%% maxwidth is the original width if it is less than linewidth
%% otherwise use linewidth (to make sure the graphics do not exceed the margin)
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{ %
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\definecolor{fgcolor}{rgb}{0.345, 0.345, 0.345}
\newcommand{\hlnum}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.686,0.059,0.569}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstr}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.192,0.494,0.8}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlcom}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.678,0.584,0.686}{\textit{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlopt}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlstd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.345,0.345,0.345}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwa}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.161,0.373,0.58}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwb}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.353,0.396}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwc}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.333,0.667,0.333}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\hlkwd}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.737,0.353,0.396}{\textbf{#1}}}%

\usepackage{framed}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{kframe}{%
 \def\at@end@of@kframe{}%
 \ifinner\ifhmode%
  \def\at@end@of@kframe{\end{minipage}}%
  \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}%
 \fi\fi%
 \def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin \hskip-\fboxsep
 \colorbox{shadecolor}{##1}\hskip-\fboxsep
     % There is no \\@totalrightmargin, so:
     \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
 \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
   \@totalleftmargin\z@ \linewidth\hsize
   \@setminipage}}%
 {\par\unskip\endMakeFramed%
 \at@end@of@kframe}
\makeatother

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.97, .97, .97}
\definecolor{messagecolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{warningcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 1}
\definecolor{errorcolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 0}
\newenvironment{knitrout}{}{} % an empty environment to be redefined in TeX

\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}

\begin{document}


% latex.default(mx, n.rgroup = c(2), rgroup = c("Nice!"), n.cgroup = c(2,      1), cgroup = c("First", "Second"), file = "", ctable = TRUE) 
%
\ctable[label=mx,pos=!tbp,]{lrrcr}{}{\FL
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries mx}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries First}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries }&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Second}\NN
\cline{2-3} \cline{5-5}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Col A}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Col B}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Col C}\ML
{\bfseries Nice!}&&&&\NN
~~A&$1$&$3$&&$5$\NN
~~B&$2$&$4$&&$6$\LL
}



\end{document}
```

and when I run tools::texi2pdf('test.tex'), I got some error message:

```
texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  'tester3.tex''texi2dvi'
Messages:
/usr/bin/texi2dvi: pdflatex exited with bad status, quitting.
/usr/bin/texi2dvi: see tester3.log for errors.
 1: tools::texi2pdf("tester3.tex")
 2: texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet, texi2dvi = texi2dvi, texinputs = texinputs, index = index)
 3: stop(msg, domain = NA)
```

Anyone knows how this happened?

thanks!

Comment: Try remove `ctable=TRUE` argument. Also you should to inspect tester3.log about errors.